# upload file with sails.js dropzone.js and formidable: Request aborted

Tags: node.js, sails.js, dropzone.js, formidable

I would like to upload multiple image files to my server. On the client side I m using dropzone.js. My back-end server is sails.js and I would like to use formidable in order to update the client with a progress-bar ( I am fairly new to sails.js and node.js)

This is my controller (written with typescript)

```html
export var upload = function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next) {
    
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {            
    });

    form.on('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        // calculating perscent and logging progress message
    });

    form.on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err); // --> here I get "Request aborted"
    });

    form.on('end', function (fields, files) {
        // here I save files to disk with fs-extra and I
        // send back to client appropriate status 
    });    
}
```

I keep getting 'Request aborted' in the error handler. I have made a few search on stackoverflow and on google without findind a clear answer. The problem seems to be related to multi-part form data and the appropriate express middleware to use in order to parse the body. How can I set my sails.js application in order to upload a file using dropzone.js on the client and sails+formidable on the server?

Any help will be greatly appreciate

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with typescript but usually in `sails.js`, you just pass `fn(req, res, next)` in your controllers. I'm not sure what `res: express.Response` means

Comment: Don't worry. They are remove by the typescript compiler during the build process so that the actual output  .js file used in the application is as you would expect: fn(req, res, next) { .... }

Comment: Hey, did you find the way to work with SailsJs and Formidable. I also get the 'Request aborted' message. I did realize the request made for uploading  files stucks on Pending state, and also `form.progress(...)` does not initialize. I think it can be `var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();` is executed in a different timing and its event does not match with the files sent.

Answer (score 0):

With Dropzone and Sails.js, you have to:

add the definination of the filename in dropzone configuration:
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { paramName: "fileName" }

use this command to get back the uploaded file:
req.file('fileName').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles) {

});

uploadedFiles contains the file